# I am not understanding ad mob policy

Tags: android, admob, google-play-developer-api

I am a beginner in app developer. i have recently published my app on google play market, i have integrated ads via Ad-mob. and selected "Automatic payment" method. but i am not understanding this payment method. why should i pay to Ad-mob? what if i earn nothing in few months, but they kept on deducting money from my account. I am not able to understand any of the term of ad-mobs policy. please explain me how does ad-mob works and will i have to pay for publishing my apps?
my threshold is showing to 50 $ what does that mean? with a validity of 30 days. Does that mean i will be charged 50$ for just monetizing ads in my app.
As far i understood that after 30 days i will be deducted 50$ from my bank account.

Comment: I think you may be paying to display ads on other peoples apps.

Comment: what if i dont want to display my app on others ad

Answer (score 1):

If they keep deducting money from your account it sounds like you are probably advertising your app in other apps. For this service ad mob charges you if they get clicked or if they just get displayed to the user. (I think that depends on your setting..)

I have ad mob in my app and I am not paying any money. So if you are just displaying ads in your app you will get payed for clicks.

The threshold of 50$ could also be that a payoff only happens if you reach the threshold of 50$ within a month. That means if you earn 49$ in April you won't get payed at the appointed day. But if you earn one more buck in May you will get payed the 50$ in May at the appointed day. To make sure what it exactly means I recommend you to get in contact with ad-mob support service.

Comment: i have recently published my app and it will take some time to appear on play store , and meanwhile i accidentally created billing account in ad-mob instead of payment  account to get payment and now i want to cancel it how to remove my debit card to not get any money deducted from my account as far now no money has been deducted but i am afraid they will deduct money , how to cancel my account before they deduct any money

Comment: @arsalan khan I just were able to find this contact possibility for ad mob: https://support.google.com/admob/contact/approval_process. I know your issue is not an approval issue but give it a try.